# Magnific Popup with Base64 image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, magnific-popup

```
<a href=@String.Format("{0},{1}", "data:image;base64", Model.PurchaseInformation.ReceiptImageBase) id="receipt-image"></a>
```

I have the above in my VIEW.... I am trying to get magnifico popup to show this image and it simply won't do it... Has anyone been able to use a button click event to pull a base64 image element and use it with magnific popup??

Comment: This is the original code I was trying to get to work...<img src=@String.Format("{0},{1}", "data:image;base64", Model.PurchaseInformation.ReceiptImageBase) id="receipt-image" />

Comment: Please post more code such as the javascript that is calling Magnific. What error are you getting? Which browser(s) have you tried?